# The best way of adding Services with multiple instances but same IOptions model

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton

I have implemented the IndexBuilderSettings which is a model for some Services, such like when I created one for that will like below

```
services.AddSingleton<SearchBrandBuilder>()
    .Configure<IndexBuilderSettings>((settings) =>
    {
        Configuration.GetSection("SearchBrandConfig").Bind(settings);
    });
```

And the `SearchBrandBuilder` is using IOptions construction

```
public class SearchBrandBuilder : SearchIndexBuilder<SearchBrandModel>
{
    public SearchBrandBuilder(IOptions<IndexBuilderSettings> opts);
}
```

But the problem is when I have to create another one, like `SearchUnitBuilder` with the same IOptions constructor, the `Configure()` seems can't help because it will be overwritten due to its singleton pattern, please noticed that I would like to keep the settings json like this

```
  "SearchBrandConfig": {
    "AdminApiKey": "456",
    "IndexName": "new-brands",
    "SearchServiceName": "search_name"
  },
  "SearchUnitConfig": {
    "AdminApiKey": "123",
    "IndexName": "new-units",
    "SearchServiceName": "search_name"
  },
```

I also don't want to rewrite the library model as IOptionsSnapshot which will inject via the name to distinguish. https://andrewlock.net/using-multiple-instances-of-strongly-typed-settings-with-named-options-in-net-core-2-x/

So the guide from link would be like this, but I won't prefer

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<SlackApiSettings>("Dev", Configuration.GetSection("SlackApi:DevChannel")); 
    services.Configure<SlackApiSettings>("General", Configuration.GetSection("SlackApi:GeneralChannel")); 
    services.Configure<SlackApiSettings>("Public", Configuration.GetSection("SlackApi:PublicChannel")); 
}
```

So, I would like to use Configuration as temporary in the Startup, I found out that it could be done by below code, a little bit workaround

```
services.AddSingleton<SearchBrandBuilder>(
    new SearchBrandBuilder(Options.Create(Configuration.GetSection("SearchBrandConfig").Get<IndexBuilderSettings>())));

services.AddSingleton<SearchUnitBuilder>(
    new SearchUnitBuilder(Options.Create(Configuration.GetSection("SearchUnitConfig").Get<IndexBuilderSettings>())));
```

I see it is a acceptance solution, but I would like to ask if whether any better solution for that? Something like a built-in function:

```
services.AddSingletonWithSetting<SearchUnitBuilder, IndexBuilderSettings>(settings => 
    Configuration.GetSection("SearchUnitConfig").Bind(settings));
```

Or any regular solution for dealing this case?

Comment: Depends on concrete case, but if there are other dependencies personally I would just create `Search{Type}Config`'s inheriting from `IndexBuilderSettings` and register/inject them separetely.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use *named options* with `IOptionsSnapshot`... I'm personally not huge fan, however they are useful in certain use cases. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

**Given**

```
services.Configure<Config>("SomeConfig", Configuration.GetSection("SomeSection"));
services.Configure<Config>("AnotherConfig", Configuration.GetSection("AnotherSection"));
```

**Implementation**

```
public class SomeClass 
{
   ...

   public SomeClass(IOptionsSnapshot<Config> namedOptionsAccessor)
   {
      _config1 = namedOptionsAccessor.Get("SomeConfig");
      _config2 = namedOptionsAccessor.Get("AnotherConfig");
   }

   ...
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#named-options-support-using-iconfigurenamedoptions)

Comment: OP mentioned this technique in the question, but wrote that it is not preferable.

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral, I have checked this technique before, but it need to rewrite library basically, I could change it, but it would be bad if the library is from other public.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer creating child config instances inheriting from base ine containing all properties:

```
public class SearchBrandConfig : IndexBuilderSettings {}
public class SearchUnitConfig : IndexBuilderSettings {}
```

And then registering and resolving them accrodingly:

```
services.Configure<SearchBrandConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SearchBrandConfig"));
services.Configure<SearchUnitConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SearchUnitConfig "));
```

And

```
public class SearchBrandBuilder : SearchIndexBuilder<SearchBrandModel>
{
    public SearchBrandBuilder(IOptions<SearchBrandConfig> opts);
}

public class SearchUnitBuilder : SearchIndexBuilder<SearchUnitModel>
{
    public SearchUnitBuilder(IOptions<SearchUnitConfig> opts);
}
```

If there are a lot of such builders - you can even partly automate registration with some reflection.

Comment: Thanks @Guru, I have also checked this technique before, but it need to rewrite library basically, I could change it, but imagine that it would be bad if the library is from other public. So I just prefer the implementation from our using scope